# NSDateFormatter dateFromString

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

The string which comes from my data source is formatted like this:

> 2011-04-11 23:12:05

```
// dateString comes from my data source, and look like I've said like this.
dateString = @"2011-04-11 23:12:05";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

When I've searched internet after threads like these the answer has always been that the dateString had wrong format. But my dateString is one of the correct ones, right?

Why does date returns nil?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A date format string of `@"MMMM"` means that the string you're trying to parse is the full name of a month ("January", "October", etc).

You want something more like:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Check out the [date formatting patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more info.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I _wanted_ to have a NSString with the full month name from my *dateString.

Comment: dateFromString will produce an NSDate - not a string.

Comment: My thought was that if I convert the string to a date, and the line after convert date to the month name (string). But I can't get past the first step. Are you with me?

Comment: Now I understand you Dave. My code now is this:
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];  
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
  NSString *month = [dateFormat stringFromDate: date];
  [dateFormat release];
Thank you!

Comment: If I want to type out the month name in my language which is Swedish, then I have to take a look at the property locale?

Comment: @Fernando that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: This format is incorrect. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Note the lowercase `y` for the year.

Answer (score 1):

```
// set norwegian locale
    dateFormatter.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"no_NO"];;

    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
    NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    NSLog(@"month: %@", monthString);
```

This is a norwegian example. With your language it should be "se_SE"