# NSDateFormatter returns NULL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

All I am trying to do is to format a date in "EEEE, MMMM dd" format (e.g. "Saturday, January 11"). No matter what I do, I get a null result.

```
- (NSString *) formatDate : (NSDate *) date
{
    if (!date)
        NSLog(@"what is going on!");

    NSLog(@"%@", date);
    NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];
    NSLog(@"%@", strDate);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd"];

    NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

    NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedDate]);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedDate];
}
```

Here is my output:

```
2014-01-12
2014-01-12
Formatted Date: (null)
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I'm following the first 4 lines from the accepted solution of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583984/objective-c-converting-date-string-into-day-of-the-week-month-name).

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly? Your format string clearly doesn't match the format of `strDate`.

Comment: I want to return a string in the format "Saturday, January 11"

Comment: How do you figure that will happen when your _input_ to the formatter is a string, and your output is a date?

Comment: Well, I'd like to not do all of this date-string-date-string conversion stuff, but I can't find anywhere in the API where I can just send an NSDate to the NSDateFormatter. I'm sure it's in there somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: [`stringFromDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBFIDDA)

Comment: OK, but then my input to the formatter is still a string - just as you  criticized!

Comment: What. `string` ****FROM**** `Date:`. Input date. Output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd"];

    NSString *returnString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@", returnString);

    return returnString;
}
```

You need to use [`stringFromDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBFIDDA), not `dateFromString:`.

I get this logged

> 2014-01-12 00:14:20.096 StackOverFlowDate[84614:a0b] Formatted Date: Sunday, January 12

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same null output. I'd tried this prior to posting.

Comment: That is literally impossible if you pass non-`nil` to the formatter, @usr.

Comment: @usr55410 - Fixed the return value (which may be the problem) - Also I'm seeing the correct date in NSLog which I added. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: Nope. I just copied your code right into mine, and I still get the null output. Something weird is going on.

Comment: @JoshCaswell What do you mean?  I'm passing in the date passed into the function?

Comment: I'm saying your code is completely correct, @ansible, and can't produce `@"(null)"` as usr55410 says unless the date is `nil`.

Comment: Okay - try this, it doesn't depend on the passed in value it will just use the current date instead and should be one less thing to go wrong.

Comment: Well, that takes care of the null error, so I've narrowed down where my problem is. Thanks for your help. I'll accept the answer and then try to figure out how my date can be nil, and yet still pass the first conditional and output correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Your new conditional at the top doesn't stop the rest of the method from running, @usr. You need a `return` statement in the body of the `if`.

Comment: I'm not trying to stop it from running. Just testing to see if the date input is `nil`. Since no output generates, I know that the variable is not `nil`. But I can't explain why the formatted date is `null` if the date is not `nil`. Thus, my dilemma

Comment: @usr55410 The problem is `NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];`.  To see this try `NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-01-12"]; NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@", tempDate);`.  I'm not an expert with NSDateFormatter, but I'm guessing it wants the date in the formatter you specified?  So your date that is passed in is fine, passed the first if check, gets turned into 2014-01-12, then back into a date, but the formatter is returning nil instead.

Comment: Dates don't have formats, @ansible. The formatter will always return an `NSString` from `stringFromDate:` _unless_ the date is `nil`. If it's a valid `NSDate`, even if the format string is junk, a valid `NSString` -- maybe even an empty string -- will come out.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell - I was talking about his call to `dateFromString:` not `stringFromDate:`.  I was guessing that the reason why his `NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];` didn't work is that it was expecting a format `Sunday, January 12` and not `2014-01-12` which seems to be the case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895697/nsdateformatter-datefromstring - dates don't have a format, but NSDateFormatter does :)

Comment: Yes indeed, @ansible; that's the reason OP's original code wasn't working.